# Chart js custom datalabel from array

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to put datalabels from calculated array on top of every column. Values in my array are representing how much every bar is filled with another color. I made a function which is calculating those values in percentage. Any tip what to put in datalabels formatter section?

[image]

```
var data1 = ['7.8', '5', '', '', '7.7', '7.8', '8.1', '7.8'];
var data2 = ['8', '8', '', '', '8', '8', '8', '8'];
var percentage = [];

function calculate() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    percentage.push(data1[i] / data2[i] * 100)
  }
}

calculate();
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
  labels: ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'],
  datasets: [{
    //   xAxisID: "bar-x-axis2",
    data: data1,
    backgroundColor: ['#c3cd46', '#e31c24', '#FFFFFF', '#FFFFFF', '#c3cd46', '#267533', '#267533', '#267533'],
    datalabels: {
      display: false,
    },
  }, {
    data: data2,
    //  xAxisID: "bar-x-axis1",
    datalabels: {
      display: false,
    },
    backgroundColor: ['rgba(61, 146, 125, 1)', 'rgba(61, 146, 125, 1)', 'rgba(61, 146, 125, 1)', 'rgba(61, 146, 125, 1)', 'rgba(61, 146, 125, 1)', 'rgba(61, 146, 125, 1)', 'rgba(61, 146, 125, 1)', 'rgba(61, 146, 125, 1)'],
  }, {
    data: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
  }]
};
var option = {
  legend: {
    display: false,
  },
  tooltips: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      scaleFontSize: 40,
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
      },
      ticks: {
        max: 10,
        min: 0,
        stepSize: 2,
        beginAtZero: true,
        callback: function(value) {
          return value + " h"
        }
      },
    }],
    xAxes: [{
      barThickness: 15,
      stacked: true,      
    }],
  },
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      anchor: 'end',
      align: 'top', 
      formatter: function(context) {

      },      
    }
  }
};

var myBarChart = Chart.Bar(canvas, {
  data: data,
  options: option
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L3rb10md/76/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you where so close to the solution.

So first things first you don't need that `var percentage`, we will change your `function calculate` a bit, and also finalize that `plugin...formatter`.

**If you wanna skip all this** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1mp8x4ay/) **for the whole changed code.**

Basically the formatter can give you the current object, which will include the `dataIndex` that we can use on the calculate function rather than looping all datasets every time.

```
function calculate(i){
    return (data1[i] / data2[i] * 100)
}
```

Note: argument " **i** " will be passed from the formatter (`chart_obj.dataIndex`).

The formater will look like this, note the second argument **`chart_obj`**

```
formatter: function(context, chart_obj) {
    return calculate(chart_obj.dataIndex); //pass the current data index to calculate
}
```

Lastly we need to set the **second** `datalabels.display = true`

```
more above ...
data: data2,
//  xAxisID: "bar-x-axis1",
datalabels: {
  display: true,
}
... more bellow
```

Hope this will help!

**Good Coding**

---

> **EDIT**

Using the `plugin option` changes the data for ALL labels, for this case I placed the `formatter` directly on the `dataset`

```
{
data: data2,
//  xAxisID: "bar-x-axis1",
datalabels: {
  display: true,
  formatter: function(context, chart_obj) {
    return calculate(chart_obj.dataIndex)
  },
}
```

Comment: How to prevent that percentages are printed out twice? Once is at the top of of the bar and second output is a bit higher than bottom? Because I need to print it only once.

Comment: @ZeroZek, I have corrected that. Basically the `plugins.formatter` will change options for ALL labels of that chart. https://jsfiddle.net/1mp8x4ay
To solve it i have put the `formatter` directly on the dataset